# Transform json Array to use as a google map marker

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am newbie and working my way so happy to get all the ideas I can. I have an external system which sends me this json file

[149.9900000,-33.8900000,\"Hume Hwy, Table Top\"],[151.5400000,-33.0400000,\"Newport Rd, Dora Creek\"]

I am not sure how I can convert this into a something like this

```
{"markers":[{"name":"Hume Hwy, Table Top","position":[149.9900000,-33.8900000],},{"name":"Newport Rd, Dora Creek","location":[151.5400000,-33.0400000]}}]}
```

so that I can consume into google maps.

Cheers 
Nick

Comment: You can extract individual values form your array and add it into the object that you require.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how too. Please can you help.

Comment: Ok wait, I will write answer to your question.

Comment: Does your server send stringified json file ? which is in a proper json structure that is parseable in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your server sends proper `JSON` structure what you can do is parse the string to object using `JSON.parse` in browser by doing `JSON.parse(response)`.

I am assuming your server sends;

`"[[149.99,-33.89,\"Hume Hwy, Table Top\"],[151.54,-33.04,\"Newport Rd, Dora Creek\"]]"` which is a multidimensional proper json response.

We can parse this response and then map the response properly into your required object, so;

- Parse the response:

```
const parsedMarkerData = JSON.parse("[[149.99,-33.89,\"Hume Hwy, Table Top\"],[151.54,-33.04,\"Newport Rd, Dora Creek\"]]");
```

- Convert into your required structure:

```
const markers = [];
for(const marker of parsedMarkerData){
  // destructuring the array
  const [x, y, name] = marker;
  // putting into object
  markers.push({
    name, position: [x, y]
  });
}
```

- Combining the response into the object with marker key:

```
const finalObject = { markers };
```

Finally, `finalObject` contains the your required structure that can be consumed into google maps.

Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-ride-x3wjo?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to view all the parts running together.

Comment: No luck with this, [149.9900000,-33.8900000,"Hume Hwy, Table Top"],[151.5400000,-33.0400000,"Newport Rd, Dora Creek"],[149.2300000,-34.4200000,"Olympic Hwy, Table Top"]    `const parsedMarkerData = JSON.parse[mylocation]` console.log(parsedMarkerData); console shows undefined. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Something like this does not work      var mymarker = JSON.stringify(mylocation);
const parsedMarkerData = JSON.parse[mymarker]
console.log(parsedMarkerData);

Comment: `Json.parse[]` are you using square brackets instead of `json.parse()`, parenthesis ?

Comment: const parsedMarkerData = JSON.parse[mylocation]; I have changed my json to { "position":[149.9900000,-33.8900000],"Incident":"Hume Hwy, Table Top" }